# how to know device use eth0 or eth1 of network card

Tags: android

i have two network card on my device.user can insert cable to anyone of network card,so i want to know which network card user is used.because i only know eth0 or eth1 is used,i can set it.

```
    DevInfo.setGateWay("192.168.85.255");
    DevInfo.setIfName("eth0");
    DevInfo.setIpAddress("192.168.84.134");
    DevInfo.setNetMask("255.255.254.0");
```

you can see the above code,i Hard coded using eth0。 is there a method to check  user use eth0 or eth1?

edit:use mean,user insert the cable,in other words, how to know which network card is insert the cable. i can modify the firmware,but i donot know where is code i can modify.

Comment: See the edits to my answer for a link to a similar question

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, because to query the physical state of the network card you'd need to access [operating system interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7101297/315306), and I don't think they are visible to the Android Java API. But if you really need it, and especially if you target a small set of devices, you may be able to develop the native parts, possibly by modifying the firmware.

Note that the question itself, *"is there a method to check user use eth0 or eth1"* is too vague: user may *use* both eth0 and eth1, or neither. The names of the interfaces may change. And what does **use** mean? The routing table of the device may be configured so that both are used to access different networks. I guess you are interested in the iface used to connect to the default gateway, but this is just an assumption and you should really clarify what you need to understand:

- if what you want to do can be done
- if it can be done with a simple app

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/808560/315306) for how to query the status of network cards (basically by polling `/sys/class/net`, but I don't know if it's working on your target devices) and how to intercept the plug/unplug event (by using [rtnetlink](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/rtnetlink.7.html) and udev, again not sure it will work on your devices). I just want to stress once again that knowing the physical state of the cards may not be enough to fulfil your high-level requirements